# Azure Kanban Board Columns State Mapping

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

How can I add values to the State Mapping Column Settings on the Kanban board?
My project shows currenly only 3 options. New, Approved and Committed. I need to add Pending Verification and Cannot Reproduce states, otherwise I cannot move items to the respective columns. The items desapear when I do so as my columns have the wrong state assigned.

[image: State mapping column settings missing entries]

I could not find anything online. I tried to find this information on the WIT xml files. No luck so far

### TIA

### UPDATE Nov 16, 2022

This is what I see when I select Process. I don't have dropdown options or links. I can only export the process. Would that be because I don't have the correct permission to change it? if so, would you know what permissions I would need?

[image: unable to change process]

---

### UPDATE Nov 17, 2022

As I continue investigating this, so far I have figured these out:

1. Process Templates are used to create projects, but once the project
   is created no link is created to the process used.
2. There is a tool I can use on VS to View/Edit the current WIT of my
   projects.
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte
   (works with VS2019, but not 2022)
3. I was able to update my Bug and Backlog Item WIT using (exporting,
   changing the XML, and importing it back to the server.
4. My bugs and backlog items now have Pending Verification and Cannot
   reproduce state. But my Kanban Column mapping state still doesn't
   show these options. Would that be a bug or am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the path: **Organization Settings->Boards->process->select Agile Process(for example)->select a work item type ->State**
And Click `new state` to add a state value.

For example:

[image: add state]

Result

[image: column settings]

For more information about category states, please refer to doc:
[How workflow category states are used in Azure Boards backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#category-states)

**UPDATE**

If you can't see the option Organization settings, please visit the URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{your organization name}/
```

you will see your organizations and "Organization Settings" is in the lower left corner.
[image: Organization Settings]

**UPDATE11/16**

If you can see a Collection Settings in your main page, click "Collection Settings", select "Process" menu and choose a process and click it .
[image: collection settings]

then select a work item type click it and switch to "state".

[image: add state]

**UPDATE11/18/2022**

There is a note:"If a workflow state isn't mapped to a Kanban column, that state doesn't appear on the Kanban board. It's allowed, but we don't recommend it."

please refer to doc: [what is workflow state mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-columns?view=azure-devops#what-is-workflow-state-mapping)

Comment: Hi, I don't see the option Organization settings. Would that be different in an On-Premisses environment?

Comment: @userMA  I've updated my answer and you can see the option Organization settings by the above steps.

Comment: I'm using on-premises Azure DevOps with TFVC. I don't access is using the azure link. It might be the reason I'm not seen the Organization Settings. If I go to my main page I see a Collection Settings. From there I can go to Process and I see a list of processes, where de default one is Agile. But if I go to any of my projects, on the setting, it doesn't show me on what process was my project created based on.  I see no way of editing my project process. But it got be possible, because some of my projects have different options for the column state. I just can't figure it out. Should be simple

Comment: @userMA  I've updated my answer . I test in my on-premises Azure DevOps and it works.

Comment: I've updated my question with an image of what I see when I select Process. I don't have the option to edit it.

Comment: I think I have all the permissions... maybe the version? I'm using Azure DevOps Server
Version Dev17.M153.5

Comment: I can't get around the fact that I cannot see what process was used on each project. At least 3 of my projects have different column map settings options. Does it mean each one was created using a different process? or is there a way to update the project process?

Comment: @userMA I've updated my answer .Hope it can help you.